# A program like man but which gives only examples

Tags: shell

I remember once seeing a command line program that gave only examples of how to use a given command. It billed itself as a companion to "man" if I remember correctly.

I can't remember the name of the project.

It was not web-based like the commandline fu website, although it had similar content. It was not like explainshell.com

Does anyone know the name of the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant:
tldr - [Homepage](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr)
cheat.sh - [Homepage](https://github.com/chubin/cheat.sh)
quite-intriguing - [Homepage](https://github.com/uriel1998/quite-intriguing)